# folder.revokePermissions fails to revoke permissions

Tags: google-apps-script, permissions, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

Can anyone help me figure out why this revokeAdminPermissions function is not working?  It executes, and the Execution Transcript states that it's successful, but the permissions are not revoked; the user still has access to the folders in question.

AddAdminPermissions and findFolder included for reference only, those are working fine.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help!

```
function findFolder(folderName){
     var folders = DriveApp.getFolders(); 
     while (folders.hasNext()) {
        var folder = folders.next();
        if(folder.getName()==folderName){
           return folder
        }
     }
  }


function addAdminPermissions(email){
   findFolder("Admin").addEditor(email)
   findFolder("Project Sheets").addEditor(email)
   findFolder("Team Members").addEditor(email) 
}

function revokeAdminPermissions(email){
   var admin = findFolder("Admin")
   admin.revokePermissions(email)
   var projects = findFolder("Project Sheets")
   projects.revokePermissions(email)
   var tmFolder = findFolder("Team Members")
   tmFolder.revokePermissions(email)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation from [revokePermissions(user)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#revokepermissionsuser), it says that:

> This method does not block users from accessing the File if they
>   belong to a class of users who have general access — for example, if
>   the File is shared with the user's entire domain.

Comment: Right, that's not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around this by calling folder.removeEditor(email) and folder.removeViewer(email).  Doesn't explain the failure, but at least it works